# Very odd Cordova/Phonegap JSON error: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, cordova, phonegap

So i've been developing an app for the past few weeks. I have never messed with any json file whatsoever. Today I tried to run my app and it shows a very odd error from Cordova, Error:

```
Error: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
```

The token is ' '?
Which JSON file is it? I went over all the main Json package files, and all of them started with the 0'th token as a '{'.

I'm completely lost, I didn't do anything at all, I didn't add a plugin or something that day it just appeared out of no where.
I have no idea which json files to attach here, there are dozens of them in the project directory.. Any ideas or direction will be extremely helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of context around the error? - in VS TACO I'd say post the output from the Build but I don't know what IDE you're using. There are lots of JSON files within a typical cordova app - each plugin you use has a package.json file and there is also a build.json file. Hopefully some context will help to narrow this down

Comment: Does remove then add platform again helps?

Answer (score 4):

## Check plugins/*.json

There's most likely an issue hiding in one of those files.

*For me it was an unresolved merge conflict inside `fetch.json`*

Comment: Just ran into this problems too and after I explicitly ran 'npm install', it went away.

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours looking through all the modified files in git, clean, reinstalling plugins and npm. I wouldn't have found it in fetch.json.

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm install` and it will give you more details of the error. In my case, it was an extra comma in package.json. It is a painful bug and I wish cordova explicitly mentioned where this issue was!

Answer (score 0):

You had to check the file fetch.json in Plugins folder. Fetch.json must be encode in UTF8 and at the end of the JSON, the file need to finish correctly, without a comma, like this :

```
{
  "es6-promise-plugin": {
    "source": {
      "type": "registry",
      "id": "es6-promise-plugin@^4.1.0"
    },
    "is_top_level": false,
    "variables": {}
  },
  "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {
    "source": {
      "type": "registry",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-nativestorage@^2.3.2"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
  } //No Comma
}
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

My approach to any JSON error:

1. [optional] Remove/uninstall all plugins
2. Delete all your platform directory folders (ie. browser, Android, iOS etc,), and delete the `package.json` file

   Note: Don't delete the `package-lock.json` file
3. Create a new `package.json` file by running `npm init` on your command line (run this command on your Cordova project directory).

   Make sure you create this file with the same package name you used before. If you don't remember, you can check the `config.xml` file (including the 'version').
4. Reinstall all your plugins (if you followed step 1).
5. Add your platforms.
6. Run, build your Cordova project.

   - If it fails, follow step 1 to the last step.
   - It works 100℅
   - If this doesn't work, contact me and send me your issues.